# Component-wise GLSL vector branching

Tags: shaders, glsl, optimization

I'm aware that it usually is a BAD idea to operate separately on GLSL vec's components separately.
For example:

```
//use instrinsic functions, they do the calculation on 4 components at a time.
float dot = v1.x*v2.x + v1.y * v2.y + v1.z * v2.z; //WRONG
float dot = dot(v1, v2); //RIGHT

//Multiply one by one is bad too, since the ALU can do the 4 components at a time.
vec3 mul = vec3(v1.x * v2.x, v1.y * v2.y, v1.z * v2.z); //WRONG
vec3 mul = v1 * v2; //RIGHT
```

I've been struggling thinking, **are there equivalent operations for branching?**

For example:

```
vec4 Overlay(vec4 v1, vec4 v2, vec4 opacity)
{
    bvec4 less = lessThan(v1, vec4(0.5));
    vec4 blend;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if(less[i]) {
            blend[i] = 2.0 * v1[i] * v2[i];
        } else {
            blend[i] = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - v1[i]) * (1.0 - v2[i]);
        }
    }
    return v1 + (blend - v1) * opacity;
}
```

This is a Overlay operator that works component wise. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, since I'm afraid these `for` and `if` can be a bottleneck later.

Tl;dr, Can I branch component wise? If yes, how can I optimize that Overlay function with it?

Comment: It's less accurate to say that "branching is bad" rather than "**divergent** branching is bad." Things work reasonably well if all active lanes in a wave take the same branch.

Comment: Yes you're right! Indeed the example of an `Overlay filter` is such example which the branch diverges a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can optimize this to be branchless actually, however for seeing if it's faster you always want to profile it:

```
vec4 Overlay(vec4 v1, vec4 v2, vec4 opacity)
{
    bvec4 less = lessThan(v1, vec4(0.5));
    vec4 blendHigh = vec4(1.0) - vec4(2.0) * (vec4(1.0) - v1) * (vec4(1.0) - v2);
    vec4 blendLow = vec4(2.0) * v1 * v2;
    vec4 blend = mix(blendHigh, blendLow, less);

    return v1 + (blend-v1)*opacity;
}
```

Notice that `mix(vec, vec, bvec)` DO NOT work on most GL ES implementations, so just use it if you're working just with desktop. (But you can test it on mobile if you wish so)

EDIT:
Here's an optimized version making use of swizzle masks and MADs (note the algorithm is the same, it was just rearranged.)

```
vec4 Overlay(vec4 v1, vec4 v2, vec4 opacity)
{
    const vec3 constants = vec3(1.0, 2.0, 0.5);
    bvec4 less = lessThan(v1, constants.zzzz);
    vec4 blendLow = v1 * v2 * constants.yyyy;
    vec4 blendHigh = constants.yyyy * (v2 + v1) - blendLow - constants.xxxx;
    vec4 blend = mix(blendHigh, blendLow, less);

    return v1 + (blend-v1) * opacity;
}
```

Comment: Me and @Kevin worked our way on the chat to optimize it to not use branches, this works fine and the answer will be accepted, though, I still am interested if there are someway to do component-wise branching.